# My loop doesn't seem to work - numerical evaluation of an integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, evaluation

So this is my code:

```
Do[N[(2/Pi)*Integrate[Sin[i*x]/Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi/i}]], {i, 5, 15, 5}]
```

I would like to repeat

```
N[(2/Pi)*Integrate[Sin[i*x]/Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi/i}]]
```

several times (for example from 5 to 15 step of 5, but also say from 5 to 50 step 5). I.e. I would like to find the value of the integral $$\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{i}}\frac{\sin{ix}}{\sin{x}}dx$$ for different values of $i$. How can I improve my code? So far it just gives me

```
    {-1, 1 + 20 System`TrigToRadicalsDump`y$170978 - 
  80 System`TrigToRadicalsDump`y$170978^3 + 
  64 System`TrigToRadicalsDump`y$170978^5 - Factor`VarForAlgebraic[1]}
```

Comment: Use Table instead of Do. The latter does not give output.

Comment: @FredSimons is right, but I'm confused about that output. I don't get any output at all when I evaluate your `Do[ ... ]` code, as should happen. Do you have some lingering definitions anywhere? Try quitting the kernel, use `Table`, and try again. Also: since you're doing `N` at the end anyway, use `NIntegrate`. It will be much faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a general solution with Integrate

```
    int[j_] = 
    Assuming[j \[Element] Integers && j > 0, 
    FullSimplify[(2/Pi)*Integrate[Sin[j*x]/Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi/j}]]]

    (*  (1/\[Pi])I (E^((I \[Pi])/
        j) (-((2 Hypergeometric2F1[1, (1 - j)/2, (3 - j)/2, E^((
        2 I \[Pi])/j)])/(-1 + j)) - (
        2 Hypergeometric2F1[1, (1 + j)/2, (3 + j)/2, E^((2 I \[Pi])/
        j)])/(1 + j)) + \[Pi] Tan[(j \[Pi])/2])     *)
```